# How can we make sure that at any point of time only one of a static method & a non-static method of a class gets called?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

Given a class having a static method & a non-static instance method,
How will you make sure that at any point of time only one of these methods gets called ?

Example:
——————

```
public class DoMath{


public static int getSum(){
//Sum
}

public int getSub(){
//Subtract
}

}
```

Now you need to make sure that at any one point of time , only either of these methods gets called.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
public class DoMath{
    public static synchronized int getSum(){
        //Sum
    }

    public int getSub(){
        synchronized(DoMath.class) {
            //Subtract
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation: a `static synchronized` method implicitly synchronizes on the `Class` object of the class that declared the method.

Comment: But can we do a class level lock on instance method?

Comment: Yes.  And that is what my implementation of `getSub` is doing.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to use a private lock holder. This prevents locking your code from outside the class. This is demonstrated in the example below. Note the order of execution in the output - DoMathExposed#getSum() cannot return before the publicly accessible class monitor is released. On the other hand, DoMathEncapsulated#getSum() returns immediately since it is synchronized on a private object, so holding the public class monitor has no effect.

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class DoMath {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("\nTesting DoMathExposed.class\n");
        DoMathExposed.x = 3;
        DoMathExposed.y = 4;
        obtainMonitorOf(DoMathExposed.class);
        System.out.println("Invoked DoMathExposed#getSum()");
        System.out.println("DoMathExposed#getSum() returned: " + DoMathExposed.getSum());

        System.out.println("\nTesting DoMathEncapsulated.class\n");
        DoMathEncapsulated.x = 1;
        DoMathEncapsulated.y = 2;
        obtainMonitorOf(DoMathEncapsulated.class);
        System.out.println("Invoked DoMathEncapsulated#getSum()");
        System.out.println("DoMathEncapsulated#getSum() returned: " + DoMathEncapsulated.getSum());
    }

    private static void obtainMonitorOf(final Class cls) throws InterruptedException {
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized(cls) {
                    System.out.println(cls.getName() + ".class MONITOR held for 10 seconds");
                    latch.countDown();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(cls.getName() + ".class MONITOR released");
            }
        }).start();
        latch.await();
    }
}


class DoMathEncapsulated {

    private static final Object lock = new Object();

    protected static int x;
    protected static int y;

    public static int getSum() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            return x + y;
        }
    }

    public int getSub() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            return x - y;
        }
    }
}

class DoMathExposed {

    protected static int x;
    protected static int y;

    public static synchronized int getSum() {
        return x + y;
    }

    public int getSub() {
        synchronized(DoMathExposed.class) {
            return x - y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the advantage of the lock Object?
I believe what you are trying to do is synchronize both the methods using class level lock?

Comment: Using a synchronized method or synchronizing on the DoMath object itself exposes the lock holder to the outer world. This means someone else may obtain the lock and block your code. Using a private lock holder is considered a best practice because it encapsulates the locking behavior within the object - DoMath in this case.

Comment: Can you give me an example where I exposed my lock holder to the outer world and it became misused. Any small example or resource  will really helping in understanding it , will be beneficial for others as well who might be searching for it now/future.